# For a given side in chess, are there as many possible winning games as losing games?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, chessboard

For a given side, e.g. white, among the total space of all possible chess games, are there as many winning games as losing games, or more of one than the other?

I cannot begin to fathom how you could answer this or prove the answer.

Comment: you could look at the number of possible positions first, then figure out how many ways there were to get to each position compare it with the number of ones that win. the hard part is enumeration of the games and positions such that all rules of chess are followed.

Comment: It depends on the players strategy, of course. If you are Black and your opponent always plays $g4$ and $f4$ as first moves, you cannot lose.

Comment: Just to clarify : You mean move-sequences not producing a draw due to 50-move rule or three-times-repetition ending with a checkmate ?

Comment: sure you can Jack you can be stupid and do a move other than Qh4. so it depends on the definition of a game, a position, etc. these may depend on what you consider a move, versus a ply. It also depends on what you call a position, does the same board configuration with a natural castle, versus a fake castle, count as different. is the same board configuration when it's whites turn, the same as one when it's blacks turn. etc.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What Jack means : If I know that the opponent starts with g4/f4, I can always win. Anyway, the question must be precised substantially to be answerable in principle.

Comment: oh I got that, I also messed up it's Qh5#  . my point is you can always win at that point, but not winning right away may lead to more winning games lines with similar strategy.  there are over 20 plays by white possible that aren't Qh5# ,and about 20 plays for black  once that other ply is made that don't block the mate , then white can Qh5#  with over 400 more lines potentially.

Comment: it will also depend on if transpositions are counted.   for black f3, f4,g4  or f3,f4,g3,g4 or f4,g3,g4 or f4,g4 or f3,g3,g4 or f3,g4 all produce similar board position for black  and can all be checkmated by white in one move in theory.

Comment: For white ( and by black later on)  sorry. my brain is messed today clearly.

Comment: There being no good reason why the numbers of winning and losing games should be equal, it is extremely likely that one is greater than the other.

Comment: I'll just add a link to the discussion https://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Ch#chess